# Google Maps vs. County Auditor

Tags: geocoding

I am manually geocoding some address data and am curious if Google maps is more up-to-date than the local county auditor websites? i.e. Butler County, Ohio

thoughts?

Comment: I think your question is very broad and open to discussion. There is not one answer to your question.

Comment: Like all questions relating to tax parcel data, the answer depends 100% on where your area of interest is. If you limit your question to a particular county it might be answerable.

Comment: I assume my question pertains more to if Google address data is driven by local county auditor data or vice versa. (which is probably googleable). 

Good day.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be sure, but when I moved into a new build house the county knew I lived there for more than a year before Google or FedEx could work it out. Remember one of them will collect taxes on the address and the others don't.